# javascript filter array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have the following code based on [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { x: [{ id: 777 }, { id: 'xx' }, { notidproperty: 987 }]},
  { id: 1111 }
];

function filterByID(obj) {
  if ('id' in obj && typeof(obj.id) === 'number' && !isNaN(obj.id)) {
    return true;
  } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') { //obj type is Object, not Array
    obj.filter(filterByID);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID);
console.log('expected length = 3, actual length = ' + arrByID.length);
console.log(arrByID);
```

How can I  filter 'arr' array ? Is there any other techniques to get proper result?

EDIT: the expected result is filtered array of objects that have id property with numeric value

So expected Id values are 15, 777, 1111

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Missing a description of what you are even wanting this code to do ... see [ask] . Note also that nothing gets returned in `else if` condition

Comment: You can probably replace `Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ) === '[object Array]')` with `Array.isArray()`

Comment: Yeah, your expected output is 3 but your actual (according to the corrected code) is 2. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, trying to get objects with a key of `id` where the value is typeof number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the following branch:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') { //obj type is Object, not Array
  obj.filter(filterByID);
}
```

This only filters but returns no result. And your object with x property of Array type will not be processed here. So:

```
if(obj.x && Array.isArray(obj.x)){
  return obj.x.filter(filterByID).length>0
}
```

Or:

```
if(obj.x && Array.isArray(obj.x)){
  obj.x = obj.x.filter(filterByID)
  return true
}
```

(Depending on what you want to do)

Comment: The second variant is exactly what I was expecting!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), because you need a flat array for the result, to count.

I use `isFinite` as check for the `id`.

```js
function rr(r, a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (Array.isArray(a[k])) {
            r = r.concat(a[k].reduce(rr, []));
        } else {
            isFinite(a.id) && r.push(a);
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var arr = [{ id: 15 }, { x: [{ id: 777 }, { id: 'xx' }, { notidproperty: 987 }] }, { id: 1111 }],
    result = arr.reduce(rr, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. In the `else if` you don't return anything. Instead of

`obj.filter(filterByID);`

try `return (obj.filter(filterByID).length > 0);`

because if the result of the recursive filterByID is an array with length more than 0, you want to add that to the outer result.